# Raspberry rc.local script not working at boot

Tags: raspberry-pi

So, this should be easy according to the internet, but of course Murphy is killing after 2hours with no results.
My backlit keyboard needs the following terminal command to properly lit:

```
xset led on
```

I want to make it happen automatically when I turn on my Raspberry pi, since It's annoying that the button on the keyboard does not work.

I created a keyboard.sh file and placed it in /home/pi/:

```
#!/bin/bash
xset led on
```

Then I edited rc.local like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/home/pi/keyboard.sh
exit 0
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: xset requires x11 and your user display, to function.   you can try to interact with the led directly using the [example here](https://askubuntu.com/a/734861).

Comment: This question is more appropraite for https://superuser.com or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @whoang, youir suggestion does turn the led on, but it does not do it automatically at boot when placed in rc.local :(

Comment: add "date > /tmp/rc-check.log" at the end of your script to see if it actually ran.   you can probably pipe your xset stderr/stdout also to confirm the no display issue.  optional to move the echo version into cron's `@reboot` as well.   mucking with echo & /sys/class/led/led1 I can get it to trigger with both `@reboot` and rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

after hour wasted with cron e rc.local I fixed it by writing a systemd service which triggers the script after the graphical interface is loaded.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.thedigitalpictureframe.com/ultimate-guide-systemd-autostart-scripts-raspberry-pi/

10 minutes and it work, I wish I found this tutorial immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file `rc.local` is executable otherwise it will not run:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Thanks to [this article](https://raspberrypi-guide.github.io/programming/run-script-on-boot) for pointing this out.

In my case, I made a backup of my `rc.local` by renaming it `rc.bak`, I then proceeded to create a new file called `rc.local` which of course does not default to executable permissions. Oops.